# facebook development using C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, facebook

I see a lots of different framework for development of app in asp.NET using C#. Please suggest a stable and well document framework for FB development.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook just announced their official [Facebook C# SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395). I didn't have a chance of playing with it yet, but that would be the one I'd start with for new apps.

There's also the [Facebook Developer Toolkit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/) by Clarity Consulting. I've used it previously, and while it works, I don't like it's object model.